# New kitchen sink - not draining properly - could it be the way plumber connected pipes?

Tags: plumbing

A plumber just installed my kitchen sink, however, it is not draining properly - it will overflow after just a few seconds. Im thinking there isnt enough pressure forcing the water down due to the downpipe having an immediate turn. He says it might be that my vent isnt connected ... however, it used to work prior and all other sinks on the floor work.

Any tips or observations would be appreciated :)[image]

Comment: That's purdy.  Many sinks have a 90 degree turn just under the basket, that should not cause a problem. Pressure does not "force the water down" gravity does unless there is problem/obstruction with the drain or vent pipe.

Comment: The problem could be your vent pipe or it could be your trap is clogged looks like there is a nut on the bottom of it for ease of cleaning. The 90 is found in many sink installations and is NOT an issue. As others have said gravity drives your water down and the difference in pressure caused by the Vent pipe (negative pressure in front of the water and positive pressure above  is what causes the water to flow, much like how a straw works in a glass of water air pressure on top of the water surface, small negative pressure in the straw and water flows..

Comment: My gut tells me that something got dislodged during the recent repair and is now clogging further downstream... have you asked the plumber to come back and snake? (ps, other sinks on the floor might not share the same vent, so the vent might still be the issue.)

Comment: The plumber snaked a full 25 feet - there was nothing blocking it downward. I suppose the vent is blocked someway .... ill get on the roof tomorrow and try to snake or force water down it.

Comment: I went up on the roof and flushed with water and then snaked about 10 feet .... still didnt help the issue - any other ideas?

the kitchen was closed 20 years ago - perhaps they put a seal or cap somewhere? though im not familiar with process